# My Variables are becoming NaN after updating in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, loss-function

So I am trying to implement DQN algorithm in tensorflow and I have defined the loss function as given below but whenever I am performing the weight update using ADAM optimizer, after 2-3 updates all my variables are becoming nan. Any idea what could be the problem. My actions can take integer values between (0,10). Any idea what might me going on?

```
def Q_Values_of_Given_State_Action(self, actions_, y_targets):


        self.dense_output=self.dense_output #Output of the online network which given the Q values of all the actions in the current state

        actions_=tf.reshape(tf.cast(actions_, tf.int32), shape=(Mini_batch,1)) #Actions which was taken by the online network
        z=tf.reshape(tf.range(tf.shape(self.dense_output)[0]), shape=(Mini_batch,1) )

        index_=tf.concat((z,actions_), axis=-1)

        self.Q_Values_Select_Actions=tf.gather_nd(self.dense_output, index_)

        self.loss_=tf.divide((tf.reduce_sum (tf.square(self.Q_Values_Select_Actions-y_targets))), 2)


        return self.loss_
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your inputs are often as large as 10 suggests your gradients are exploding. You can check this by reducing the learning rate to something very small (try dividing your current learning rate by 100). If it takes longer to get NaNs, or they don't happen at all, it's your learning rate. If it's your learning rate, then consider using a one-hot vector to represent the actions.

In general, you can track down small bugs using [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) and big ones using [tfdbg](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger).